# Developing vs code extension with larger tabular output

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What do I use for output when writing an extension?

I can only see using WebView and the output.

Can I create my own "output" tab to write my, sometimes raqther large, tabular result in?

Comment: A third option might be a `TextDocumentContentProvider`, which is basically a regular, but read-only editor tab you provide the contents for.

Comment: @Gama11 as long as I can produce it to another dock that's perfectly fine. WebView just seems like it's using too much resources and for my tabular output it's definately overkill.